# Redirect to another page with a message

Tags: php, redirect, message

I want to redirect to a page and then display a message:

What I have is:

```
//succes            
$message = 'succes';
redirect_to('index.php');
```

On the index page I have:

```
if (!empty($message)) {
    echo '<p class="message"> '.$message.'</p>';
}
```

The redirect function is working fine:

```
function redirect_to( $location = NULL ) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    }
}
```

But it won't display my message. It's empty.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By the time the redirect happens and the PHP script depicted by `$location` is executed, `$message` variable would have been long gone.

To tackle this, you need to pass your message in your location header, using `GET` variable:

`header("Location: $location?message=success");`

And

```
if(!empty($_GET['message'])) {
    $message = $_GET['message'];
// rest of your code
```

You could also have a look into [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = 'success';
header("Location: $location");
```

then in the destination script:

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])) {
   $message = $_SESSION['message'];
   // rest of your code
```

Answer (score 4):

Variables cease to exist after the script ends. Each separate request, each separate PHP script invocation is an entirely new context with no data from any other invocation.

Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to persist data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sessions

```
//succes            
$_SESSION['message'] = 'succes';
redirect_to('index.php');
```

And on index

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo '<p class="message"> '.$_SESSION['message'].'</p>';
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running `header("Location: {$location}");` the value of `$location` (set in the first file) is lost when index.php is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

you can avoid redirect function and use this code in the page

```
header("Location: $locationpage?message=success")
```

index.php

```
if(!empty($_GET['message'])) {
$message = $_GET['message'];
 echo '<p class="message"> '.$message.'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following code....

```
header("Location: index.php?message=success");
```

in index.php

```
$msg=$_GET['message'];
echo $msg;
```